# R keep crashing every time I load the matlib package

Tags: r, rstudio

I tried looking on stack for some guides to this issue, but all I found was this, which 1) isn't helpful given my `libpath` shows my packages are in one location and 2) I dont get the same error message, just an instant crash:

[Why is R crashing when I try to import certain packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46305620/why-is-r-crashing-when-i-try-to-import-certain-packages)

When I load pretty much every common package I use, there is no issue and R works just fine. However, when I use `library(matlib)`, it takes a second to load and instantly crashes:

[image]

I've tried removing and reinstalling the package, but that has done nothing. This is also a brand new reinstall of RStudio (4.2.0), which was already causing issues with the text format of my scripts until I changed them. Not sure if that is helpful information, but it would be great to get some advice.

Comment: Does the same occur when you run `R` in the terminal?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72055993/2554330 .  `matlib` uses the `rgl` package, and that package had a bug that would cause this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per user2554330's suggestion, I simply ran this code in the following order:

```
options(rgl.debug = TRUE)
library(matlib)
```

Problem was fixed immediately. Thanks for the help.